# using google map api with X-callback url

Tags: ios, google-maps

I am working on a navigation app which launches GOOGLE MAP from my native app when user click on any of the pins displayed on the apple map. The location data was pulled from GOOGLE. So I used this code for block showing a callout accessory and let user get to the GOOGLE MAP

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
 {

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:[[UIViewController alloc] init] animated:YES];
    NSString* addr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=%1.6f,%1.6f&saddr", view.annotation.coordinate.latitude,view.annotation.coordinate.longitude];
    NSURL* url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[addr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
 }
```

Then I found out there is a x-callback url which can put a back button in the google map and let the user go back to my native app. but anyone know how to use these lines of codes? i have registered my app in the properties list but i have no idea what to do the next. the code from google is like this:

```
comgooglemaps-x-callback://?center=40.765819,-73.975866&zoom=14
&x-success=sourceapp://?resume=true
&x-source=SourceApp
```

Can anyone please tell me where shall i put these codes? and How to use that in my app?

Answer (score 0):

If you scroll down in the Google documentation they give example code on how to use this in iOS.
Code provided:

```
NSURL *testURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps-x-callback://"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:testURL])
{
    NSString *directionsRequest = @"comgooglemaps-x-callback://" +
    @"?daddr=John+F.+Kennedy+International+Airport,+Van+Wyck+Expressway,+Jamaica,+New+York" +
    @"&x-success=sourceapp://?resume=true&x-source=AirApp";
    NSURL *directionsURL = [NSURL URLWithString:directionsRequest];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:directionsURL];
} 
else 
{
   NSLog(@"Can't use comgooglemaps-x-callback:// on this device."); 
}
```

You would change everthing after daddr= with your address.  Also change AirApp to the name of your application.

Comment: Hi Sean, thanks for the reply. but shall I put this block of code into my calloutAccessoryControlTapped method? Another problem is about the daddr. I use currentCentre as my current location. how do i replace the airport name with current location. Or is that possible to skip the daddr part. Instead I will just put in the x-success=sourceapp part

Comment: I believe you would replace the ?daddr= with comgooglemaps://?q=Pizza&center=37.759748,-122.427135. For More information on actions checkout https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme?hl=ja#search

Comment: hey man, thanks for the help but it didn't work. maybe i am too new to objective c. when i put in the code you suggested Xcode just complained the '+'. so i have to take them off but the link wouldn't work. i replaced the code after daddr to %1.6f,%1.6f&saddr as I used in my code (posted in my question). Do you have any idea how to use it with my code?

Answer (score 0):

you should use below code :

```
    NSURL *testURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps-x-callback://"];
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:testURL]) 
    {
       NSMutableString *directionsRequest = [NSMutableString   stringWithString:@"comgooglemaps-x-callback://"];
       [directionsRequest appendFormat:@"?daddr=John+F.+Kennedy+International+Airport,+Van+Wyck+Expressway,+Jamaica,+New+York"];
       [directionsRequest appendFormat:@"&x-success=CouriorMap://?resume=true&x-source=AirApp"];
       NSURL *directionsURL = [NSURL URLWithString:directionsRequest];
       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:directionsURL];
    } 
    else 
    {
       NSLog(@"Can't use comgooglemaps-x-callback:// on this device.");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the google map call back function:

1. Add the following content to info.plist

   ```
       <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
       <array>
           <dict>
               <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
               <string>com.example.GoogleMapTest</string>
               <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
               <array>
                   <string>myapp</string>
               </array>
           </dict>
       </array>
   </dict>
   </plist>
   ```

com.example.GoogleMapTest is you app bundle id.

myapp is the url scheme just like google map's comgooglemaps://.

2. Call the function anywhere you wish:

   ```
   - (void)useGoogleMapApp {
       if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:
            [NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps://"]]) {

          NSString *url = @"comgooglemaps-x-callback://?saddr=1.294094,103.853722&daddr=1.244310,103.833386&directionsmode=transit&x-success=myapp://?resume=true&x-source=MyAppName";

           [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
       } else {
           NSLog(@"Can't use comgooglemaps://");
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Above Solution Not working.
It only open the Google Map app and there is no button to go back to the app or any callback to the app when navigation is finished